# How do I prove that reduced density matrix is Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, trace

It is known that density matrix $\rho$ is hermitian. How do I prove that for a bipartite system $AB$, reduced density matrix of $A$, $\rho_A = Tr_B\{\rho_{AB}\}$, is hermitian, given that $\rho_{AB}$ is hermitian as well?

Answer (score 5):

This can be worked out from the definition itself.

The partial trace $\text{tr}_B$ is defined as the linear extension of the mapping,
$$\text{tr}_B : S \otimes T \to \text{tr}(T)S,$$
for any matrices $S$ and $T$ on the Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $\mathcal{H}_B$, respectively.

Let ${|a_i\rangle}$ be a basis of $\mathcal{H}_A$, and ${|b_i\rangle}$ be a basis of $\mathcal{H}_B$. Any density matrix $\rho_{AB}$ on $\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ can then be decomposed as $\rho_{AB} = \sum\limits_{ijkl} m_{ijkl}|a_i\rangle \langle a_j| \otimes |b_k\rangle \langle b_l|$.

The hermiticity of the joint density matrix $\rho_{AB}^\dagger = \rho_{AB}$ implies $m_{ijkl} = m^*_{jilk}$.

The partial trace then reads $\rho_A = \text{tr}_B (\rho_{AB}) = \sum\limits_{ijkl} m_{ijkl}\langle b_l|b_k\rangle|a_i\rangle \langle a_j| $.

Since $\langle b_l| b_k \rangle = \langle b_k| b_l\rangle$, it follows that $m_{ijkl} = m^*_{jilk}$ which simply means $\rho_A = \rho^\dagger_A$.

Comment: @Neijal Kanderbalt, is there anything in my answer that confuses you? How can I clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is overly complicated in my opinion. This answer is more simple:

The solution has only 2 pieces of prerequisite knowledge:

$$(pAB)^{\dagger} = p(A B)^{\dagger}=p(B^{\dagger} A^{\dagger})$$
...and...
$$(A+B)^{\dagger}=A^{\dagger}+B^{\dagger}$$
for any 2 matrices $A$ and $B$ and some real number $p$. These 2 rules aren't too difficult to prove, with some good effort. Just write out generic matrices of an arbitrary size, and you will see.

Consider the density matrix $\rho$ for a pure state $|\psi \rangle$. By definition $\rho = |\psi \rangle \langle \psi | $.

Taking the adjoint of this gives: $\rho^{\dagger} = (|\psi \rangle \langle \psi |)^{\dagger} = \langle \psi |^{\dagger} |\psi \rangle^{\dagger} = |\psi \rangle \langle \psi | = \rho$

Taking the more general definition of a density matrix:

$$\rho=\sum_{j} p_{j}\left|\psi_{j}\right\rangle\left\langle\psi_{j}\right|$$

we can apply the first rule I listed to each of the terms $p_j\left|\psi_{j}\right\rangle\left\langle\psi_{j}\right|$, as per the second rule I listed. The addition of all the resulting hermitian matrices is also a hermitian matrix (because this holds true for the addition of any 2 hermitian matrices).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Physics! Your answer seems limited to a $2-$dimensional Hilbert space. A [bipartite](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/bipartite) system, as considered in the question, can be of an almost arbitrary number of dimensions and can't, in general, be represented by the two-dimensional vector you proposed.

Comment: ah I see! thanks for the clarification. my answer could be generalized to higher dimension spaces.

Comment: my apologies, thanks for the warm welcome!

Comment: made my proof work in the general case.